# How to do smooth Random in C# with step?

Tags: c#, random

How to generate random value from 5 to 10 with step 0.4?

I tried:

```
var numberOfSteps = 0.4;
var _step = (maximum - minimum) / numberOfSteps;
var difference = maximum - minimum;
var stepsToDifference = Math.Round(difference / _step);
return Convert.ToString(minimum + _step * stepsToDifference);
```

Comment: Considering there is no `Random` there, its very hard to say.

Comment: How I can do it with `Random`? May be generate some values fro, intrerval and add their to array. After do random select from array in interval?

Comment: So you haven't tried it with random yet? You seem awfully close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want the number to be 5, 5.4, 5.8, ... 10?  As 5 and 10 are 5 apart and not evenly divisible by .4, you will have to either stop at 9.8 or at 10.2 or stop at 10 with a short step at the last.

But here is how you can get a random number that is a member of that set (will be any number from 5 to 9.8 on the even .4 step).

```
Random rand = new Random();
float randomInSet = ((float)rand.Next(0,12)*.4)+5;
```

Please let me know if this is not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int intPart = 0;
int multiplesOfPointFour = 0;
bool doAgain = true;
double finalValue = 0.0;
while (doAgain)
{
    intPart = rand.Next(5, 8);
    multiplesOfPointFour = rand.Next(0, 6);
    finalValue = intPart + (multiplesOfPointFour * 0.4);
    Console.WriteLine("Value is: " + finalValue.ToString());
    Console.Write("Press any key to go again...");
    Console.ReadKey();                
}
```

So we pick an integer between 5 and 10 and then add 0.4 a random number of times between 0 and 12 to that integer, because 5.0 / 0.4 = 12.5

Comment: It gives me always the same `finalValue ` Also infinity loop

Comment: It is intended to loop.  If you set a break point on the closing '}', you should be able to run it and get a different value each time the loop executes.  You would fill in logic to do something with your value each time in the loop.  I'll update the answer to show what I mean as a Console App.

Comment: Also it give numbers over 10.  It's not perfect, but this is the general idea.  You cannot specify the step and range for decimals using a Random, but you could do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to generate a random Hue to create really different colors, so here it is:

```
    //***************************************************************************
    public static partial class RndExtensions
    //***************************************************************************
    {
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    public static double NextDouble(this Random rnd, double from, double to, double step)
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        var delta = to - from;
        var nbOfSteps = (int)(delta / step);
        var randomStep = rnd.Next(0, nbOfSteps);
        return step*randomStep + from; 
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    public static double Next(this Random rnd, int from, int to, int step)
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        var delta = to - from;
        var nbOfSteps = (int)(delta / step);
        var randomStep = rnd.Next(0, nbOfSteps);
        return step * randomStep + from;
    }
    }
```

Used as

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var randomHue = rnd.NextDouble(0, 359, 25);
```